# WPF canvas adding to background

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, canvas

I have canvas called `myCanvas` and `n` rectangles on him added as

```
mycanvas.Children.Add(UIElement u);
```

Later on, i need to add `Line` and bring it to the background(on the layer before rectangles).

I don't know how to explain better :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ZIndex:

```
Canvas.SetZIndex(line, 0);
```

Comment: I just replace `0` with `-1` and everything fine. Tnx :)